# How to create derived types of abstract data types in VHDL 2008?

Tags: generics, types, adt, vhdl

Using VHDL 2008 is there a way to define an abstract entity with a generic type that has ports of that type as well as unconstrained arrays or records derived from that base type? Something like this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity COMP_EXCH is
  generic(type T;                             -- VHDL-2008 abstract generic base type
          function "<"(L,R:T) return BOOLEAN; -- VHDL-2008 abstract generic function
          LATENCY:INTEGER:=0);
  port(I0,I1:in T;
       O:out T_VECTOR(0 to 1));
end COMP_EXCH;

architecture TEST of COMP_EXCH is
begin
  O<=(I1,I0) when I1<I0 else (I0,I1);
end TEST;
```

where T_VECTOR is:

type T_VECTOR is array(INTEGER range <>) of T;

and T is an arbitrary abstract base type. The challenge is how to insert the definition of T_VECTOR, which depends on T after the generic where T is introduced but before the port where T_VECTOR is neeeded? How can both types be kept generic and abstract but have one be an unconstrained array of the other? Without abstract types one would use a package to achieve this, which would contain the type definitions of T and T_VECTOR but how can it be done with abstract types in VHDL 2008?

I would like to be able to have a number of derived types like unconstrained arrays, or records (for example a complex record with real and imaginary fileds of type T) still remain abstract and use them to define abstract components like the example above.

Comment: Must it be an entity?  Would implementing as a subprogram be acceptable?

Comment: It has to be an entity. This is part of a generic sorting network design. I want to create an abstract sorting network entity that has an abstract base type T, an absract "<" function that compares two items of type T and input and output ports that are unconstrained arrays of type T. This entity would implement a sorting network of any size, sorting arrays of any type of elements using a user defined "<" function.

Comment: You would instantiate this entity by providing the type T, the compare function "<" and input and output signals which are arrays of some size of T and you would get the sorting network that you need. COMP_EXCH is just the basic building block of the larger design. I already have everything else working except this T and T_VECTOR problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question now, here is one partial solution to this problem:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

package SORTER_PKG is
  subtype T is INTEGER; -- define T here to make package "generic"
  function "<"(L,R:T) return BOOLEAN;
  type T_VECTOR is array(INTEGER range <>) of T;
end SORTER_PKG;

package body SORTER_PKG is
  function "<"(L,R:T) return BOOLEAN is
  begin
    return L<R; -- overload "<" here for whatever T is
  end;
end SORTER_PKG;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use work.SORTER_PKG.all;

entity COMP_EXCH is
  port(I0,I1:in T;
       O:out T_VECTOR(0 to 1));
end COMP_EXCH;

architecture TEST of COMP_EXCH is
  signal I:T_VECTOR(O'range);
begin
  I<=(I1,I0) when I1<I0 else (I0,I1);
end TEST;
```

The solution is "generic" in the sense that you can redefine T and "<" in one place in SORTER_PKG to make COMP_EXCH and the rest of the sorting network design sort anything without having to make any changes to that code. Although they are not realy abstract types, T and T_VECTOR behave like ones inside COMP_EXCH. The only drawback is that if you need multiple kinds of sorters in the same design with different base types T then you are out of luck - the "poor man's" abstract network sorter solution, it works but you can only use it once.

This is a workaround for solving the initial problem but not a true solution. I still don't know if it is possible in VHDL 2008 to define a record or array derived from a type generic base type T and use that in port or signal declarations without having an actual value for T. If you try to make SORTER_PKG an abstract generic pakage with a generic type T then you cannot use the package in COMP_EXCH because T doesn't have an actual value. VHDL 2008 is so close to true OOP hardware design but still not there yet.

Comment: This looks to be nearly there - you can now create a generic for T (rather than a subtype) and then instantiate the package with different Ts.  See http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ETxLguPMEY0C&lpg=PA37&ots=qao2KsYUwR&dq=vhdl%202008%20generic%20package&pg=PA37#v=onepage&q=vhdl%202008%20generic%20package&f=false

Comment: Actually I am nowhere near to having a solution to my problem, we are simply running in circles here. Yes, in VHDL 2008 you can make the SORTER_PKG have a generic type T rather than an actual subtype definition but then you cannot use that package in COMP_EXCH because it is an uninstantiated package. You need to create a new package with "package ... is new work.SORTER_PKG generic map(T=>...);" and use that in COMP_EXCH but that is just a more convoluted way of doing what my pre VHDL 2008 solution is already doing in a much simpler way.

Comment: You still have to derive an actual package for every T type you want to use and then modify COMP_EXCH and all the other files to use that package. You can still do only one T type at a time without making changes to the abstract network sorting code so the VHDL 2008 solution based on generic types is no better than my subtype based solution, it is just more complicated. Maybe I am missing the obvious here, but I do not see how you can use T_VECTOR in COMP_EXCH without actually defining T first. If you can provide an example that solves this issue I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get where you need to without creating an intermediate package with T and T_VECTOR in - then you might instantiate that package for the entity?

Alternatively (and this might not fit your ultimate goal)... can this work?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity COMP_EXCH is
  generic(type T;                             -- VHDL-2008 abstract generic base type
          function "<"(L,R:T) return BOOLEAN; -- VHDL-2008 abstract generic function
          LATENCY:INTEGER:=0);
  port(I0,I1:in T;
       O0,O1:out T);
end COMP_EXCH;

architecture TEST of COMP_EXCH is
begin
  O0<=I1 when I1<I0 else I0;
  O1<=I0 when I1<I0 else I1;
end TEST;
```

Comment: This would be OK in the particular case of COMP_EXCH, which has an output port of known size but the general sorter entity has unconstrained array ports and requires T_VECTOR. It is clear that a package is needed for the T_VECTOR definition but that is an uninstantiated package since T and "<" are not defined yet. So how do you instantiate it to use the definition of the T_VECTOR type while T is not yet defined? I can't seem to find a way to create an abstract entity that uses both T and array or record types derived from it without actually defining T.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem where I wanted to send a generic data type and an array of the same data type to an entity. My solution is generic, but a bit clumsy. I sent in both T and T_VECTOR to the entity. The problematic part is that inside the entity doesn't seem to understand that T_VECTOR is an array, so for every function that needs to do some array operation (such as getting an element from the array, I had to also send in separate functions. I think this is best demonstrated with an actual example, so here's the [RTL code](https://github.com/olofk/libaxis/blob/master/rtl/vhdl/axis_framer.vhd) and [testbench](https://github.com/olofk/libaxis/blob/master/bench/vhdl/tb_axis_framer.vhd). I think this should apply to your problem as well